# loading reCAPTCHA v3 script prints long list of data to the console and finishes with Timeout

Tags: angular, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

All of a sudden, without doing anything special I can tell, the loading of the following script prints a long list of data to the console and not returning the token.
Everything worked but now it only prints data until getting a Timeout.

That's the script I'm loading in my `index.html` which causes the mess.

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?KEY"></script>
```

The key is 100% correct since it's working on other teammates' laptops.

This is part of the log I'm getting when opening the console.

```html
hrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Screen: 1280 720 true
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Not using Worker
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Opening WebSocket wss://172-20-21-13.sslip.io:30443/cef/blaze/free.shield-browser.service.consul:8080
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Locale: 00000409
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Acceleration enabled: 40
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Screen size: 384 90
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 WebSocket connected: wss://172-20-21-13.sslip.io:30443/cef/blaze/free.shield-browser.service.consul:8080
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Communication opened
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:8 get cookies took2.6250000009895302
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Screen size: 384 90
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 URL: 172-20-21-13.sslip.io:30443
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Server: Shield Server 8.0.0.0
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Round trip: 17
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Web Audio API
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Opening audio
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Connected to '172-20-21-13.sslip.io' localhost
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Mouse wheel speed: 120
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Setting up auto resize;
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 Autoresize enabled
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:9 CEF IP ADDRESS 10.42.0.134
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:4 NAVIGATION - Recv changeUrl with current URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LdJV64UAAAAANmegCjLyoA-OYcj9Hyfd7B_BNYH&co=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0MjAw&hl=en&v=JPZ52lNx97aD96bjM7KaA0bo&size=invisible&cb=h9wqfnif7nrh" will not navigate
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 rawEvent:KeyDown: KeyboardEvent keyCodeResult Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 KB.send:keydown Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 rawEvent:KeyDown: KeyboardEvent keyCodeResult Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 KB.send:keydown Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 rawEvent:KeyDown: KeyboardEvent keyCodeResult Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 KB.send:keydown Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 rawEvent:KeyUp: KeyboardEvent keyCodeResult Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 KB.send:keyup Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 rawEvent:KeyUp: KeyboardEvent keyCodeResult Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 KB.send:keyup Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 rawEvent:KeyUp: KeyboardEvent keyCodeResult Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:7 KB.send:keyup Object
accessnow.min.0da951…c1870dafd20b75.js:6 KB.event:blur
```